Invalid Username or Password next-auth KeycloakProvider
I am trying to access the sign in page for keycloak via my next-js app. So that user can enter the username & password & then log in. But I keep getting an error of - Invalid Username or Password instead of the sign in page on this url - https://auth-jja4kcvvdq-ez.a.run.app/realms/testmobile/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=TestmobileUI&scope=openid%20email%20profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fkeycloak&state=o0GiEp75oU98G9srvnmpI8OeeImY5OcqdIh-xoG15eM&code_challenge=RkgounE2cTx8VsWDDRBBUn0ikXBBWk0VqryLX3snPwE&code_challenge_method=S256
Any help will be appreciated.
This is my [...nextauth]/route.js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';

// src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
      KeycloakProvider({
        clientId: "TestmobileUI",
        clientSecret: "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbi",
        issuer: "https://auth-jja4kcvvdq-ez.a.run.app/realms/testmobile",
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, account }) {
        console.log('JWT Callback - token:', token);
        console.log('JWT Callback - account:', account);
        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        }
        return token;
      },
      async session({ session, token }) {
        console.log('Session Callback - session:', session);
        console.log('Session Callback - token:', token);
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
        return session;
      },
    },
  };
  

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

My Login Button
const handleSignIn = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    signIn("keycloak");
  };

<button
                className="bg-[#001F3D] w-full p-2 text-white text-lg rounded-md"
                onClick={handleSignIn}
              >



what is your next-auth version

@DileepaMabulage "next-auth": "^4.24.7",

This wasn't a code issue. It was a config issue on my keycloak admin. I removed required from Identity Provider Redirector & it worked.
